# In JAVA SWT , How to display tableitem along with browse button for each item in the right side?

Tags: java, swt

[image]I am trying to display the table items for which I should have browse button at the right side to select each item's file from the file explorer

```
 `Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE );
    table.setBounds(10, 75, 250, 300);
    String modDisp[] = {"ITEM1","ITEM2","ITEM3"};
    for(int i=0;i<modDisp.length;i++)
    {
        items = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        items.setText(modDisp[i]);
    }`
```

Comment: Far easier to have one browse button that displays the currently selected table item.

Comment: I need to select different file for each item, and hence need multiple browse button

Comment: I don't see why needing different files requires different buttons. The code for the buton selection can work out which file from the selected table item.

Comment: Okay the requirement : there is one input file for one module and i need to select three different files for three modules in order to generate an output file. i have added an image for reference

Comment: I wouldn't use a Table for that at all, just a few rows of Label + Button (or Text + Button).

Comment: Can youu help with the code?